# How to get the historical Gas (Gwei) Price

Tags: gas, gas-price

I would like to get the historical Gas (Gwei) price in hourly or minutely with safelow, Standard, fast and fastest. I am aware of the etherscan.io which gives avg gas price for a day and also ethstation which gives realtime data. I am able to get the real-time from https://www.etherchain.org/tools/gasPriceOracle. Is there a way where i can get historical prices?

Answer (score 2):

You can follow this website they have provided their API as well [click here](https://ethgasstation.info/)

and you can get a lot of other detailed information as well

Answer (score 1):

You can get the historical data from the [Chainlink Price feeds fast gas proxy contract](https://feeds.chain.link/fast-gas-gwei) if you wanted to pull from an on-chain record.

You can see [the history right in the contract](https://feeds.chain.link/fast-gas-gwei)

```js
/** This example code is designed to quickly deploy an example contract using Remix.
 */

pragma solidity ^0.6.7;

import "https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/blob/master/evm-contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";

contract HistoricalPriceConsumerV3 {

    AggregatorV3Interface internal priceFeed;
    
    /**
     * Network: Mainnet
     * Aggregator: Fast Gas / Gwei Price
     * Address: 0x169E633A2D1E6c10dD91238Ba11c4A708dfEF37C
     */
    constructor() public {
        priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0x169E633A2D1E6c10dD91238Ba11c4A708dfEF37C);
    }

    /**
     * Returns historical price for a round id.
     * roundId is NOT incremental. Not all roundIds are valid.
     * You must know a valid roundId before consuming historical data.
     *
     * ROUNDID VALUES:
     *    InValid:      18446744073709562300
     *    Valid:        18446744073709562301
     *    
     * @dev A timestamp with zero value means the round is not complete and should not be used.
     */
    function getHistoricalPrice(uint80 roundId) public view returns (int256) {
        (
            uint80 id, 
            int price,
            uint startedAt,
            uint timeStamp,
            uint80 answeredInRound
        ) = priceFeed.getRoundData(roundId);
        require(timeStamp > 0, "Round not complete");
        return price;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since all the truly full length historic sources are paid in some-way, you should be able to materialize a view in bigquery using the public crypto datasets that is SQL accessible if that works for you.

Here's what I'm using:

```
SELECT 
DATE(block_timestamp) as block_date,
Format("%.*f",3,(AVG(gas_price)/1000000000)) as avg_gas_price 
FROM `bigquery-public-data.crypto_ethereum.transactions` 
-- WHERE DATE(block_timestamp) > "2022-02-20"
group by 1
order by 1 desc
```

That's daily level granularity but you can break out the block_timestamp by minute or hour if you need it.

If you can provide an algorithm for calculating safelow, standard, fast, and fastest I will build that in as well and update this answer.

Edit: more information on the `crypto_ethereum.transaction` data "source" [image]

- Github project for the loader for this: https://github.com/blockchain-etl/ethereum-etl

EDIT:

I've been able to hone in on some estimates for different transaction types that can be used to calculate the costs for those transactions historically.

It goes something like this:

```
standard_trans_eth = 21000 * avg_gas_price / 1e9
erc20_trans_eth = 65000 * avg_gas_price / 1e9
stablecoin_swap_eth = 100000 * avg_gas_price / 1e9
token_swap_eth = 200000 * avg_gas_price / 1e9
pool_deposit_eth = 300000 * avg_gas_price / 1e9
nft_mint_721_eth = 350000 * avg_gas_price / 1e9
nft_mint_1155_eth = 150000 * avg_gas_price / 1e9 
ico_contract_eth = 1000000 * avg_gas_price / 1e9
```

If you want the resulting price in usd, just multiply that `_eth` column by the historic price of eth at the time.

Example: Jan 21, 2022 when avg gas price was 185.589 & ETH opened ~3000 USD, closed ~2500 USD.

```
standard_trans_eth = 21000 gas limit * 186 gwei / 1e9 * $2750 usd = $10.75
```

Going to be working on a complete visualization / dataset of this in bigquery but this is how I'm working it so far.

EDIT 2:

Highly recommend using the "Estimated Cost of Transactions" table for representative gas limits from: https://etherchain.org/tools/gasnow

Answer (score 0):

The closest you can get is using [this](https://etherscan.io/chart/gasprice) graph of historical gas prices.

Unless somebody has been storing the data you are asking for in a database, you will not be able to retrieve it. You can, however, run the same algorithm that ethgasstation.info uses on the graph above and interpolate the data, if desired.